# saving an entity class as a serialized field

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

consider the following class structure:

```
@Entity
public class A {}

@Entity 
public class B {}

public class SubA extends A
{
   private B b;
}
```

i want to persist a `SubA` instance to the database, but JPA is detecting that the member `b` is an entity and requires me to annotated it accordingly (`@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`).

i'd like to treat the member `b` as a plain serialized field and not an entity, i.e. save a 'snapshot' of the instance and not a reference to the corresponding record of `B`.

i could of course just serialize the instance of `B` my self and save it as a byte array for example, but i was hoping there's a more elegant solution built-in JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error might occur if B is not serializable, but you should be able to specify the 'b' attribute as a basic mapping:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Basics

This will cause it to serialize it to a blob field in the A table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can serialize the SubA instance into for example JSON and store as text in the database, and parse it back to an object.
If you use EclipseLink you can implement converter class for this purpose and the process will be automated.
http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_converter.htm

In JPA 2.1 providers there are standard annotations / interfaces for the purpose.

Comment: FWIW AttributeConverters have been standard since JPA 2.1. Any JPA 2.1 implementation provides those